# Avoiding Mongoid N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'd like to pull all companies that have at least one position title of "CEO".

I could hack it together with a query for each table and an intersect (I know... no joins http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html#relational_associations, and [N+1 problem in mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912706/n1-problem-in-mongoid), and I could just embed positions in company), but any way to do something like:

Company.includes(:positions).where("positions.title" => "CEO")?

Thanks:

```
class Position
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String
  field :profile_id, type: String
  field :tenure, type: BigDecimal

  belongs_to :company, index: true

class Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :linkedin_id, type: String
  field :positions_count, type: Integer #Mongo Index

  belongs_to :industry, index: true
  has_many :positions

  index({ positions_count: 1}, {background: true})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the the N+1 problem enable Mongoid [identity_map feature](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/identity_map.html)

This will allow you to do the following query:

```
companies_with_ceo = Position.where(title: 'CEO').includes(:company).map(&:company)
```

Which should execute only 2 queries to the database.

Comment: Perfect. If a Company also has many Industries (each Industry has a name field), what's the best way to chain that on as well? (e.g. an Industry name of 'Entertainment')?

Comment: Ugly (it'd be nice to still maintain the relationships) but works...: Position.where(title: /.*CEO.*/).includes(:company).map(&:company).select{ |co| co["industry_id"]==Industry.find_by(name: "Entertainment")["_id"]}

Comment: I would try something like `entertainment_ids = Position.where(title: 'CEO').includes(:company).map(&:company).map(&:entertainment_id); Entertainment.find(entertainment_ids)` - This would execute in 3 queries instead of N+1. Please upvote the answer